# Can't find resource for bundle during Glassfish deployment

Tags: java, exception, deployment, glassfish, ear

During remote deployment of an EAR application on Glassfish 4.1.2 with no AppClient, I get the following RuntimeException caused by a org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource for bundle
java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key
enterprise.deployment.appclient.noManifest
```

How do I fix Glassfish to display the correct error message so I can determine which library is causing the deployment error? I take it one of the dependency JARs is missing a manifest file, but GF can't construct the appropriate error message because the property resource bundle does not exist. Is this a bug in GF?

```
[2017-07-11T09:57:27.797+1000] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] []
[javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=47
_ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1499731047797] [levelValue: 1000] [[   Exception while preparing the app : Can't find
resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key
enterprise.deployment.appclient.noManifest java.lang.RuntimeException:
Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key
enterprise.deployment.appclient.noManifest  at
org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.JavaEEDeployer.prepare(JavaEEDeployer.java:229)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at
org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:309)
    at
org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:88)
    at
org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:155)
    at
org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:152)
    at
org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:232)
    at
org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:283)
    at
org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:152)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at
org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)  at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)  at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at
org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:404)
    at
org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandSimpInMultOut(CommandResource.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)    at
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)   at
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)   at
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)   at
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:375)
    at
org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:173)
    at
org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at
com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at
org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Can't find
resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key
enterprise.deployment.appclient.noManifest  at
java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:450)     at
java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:407)     at
org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.AppClientDeployerHelper.generateAppClientFacade(AppClientDeployerHelper.java:533)
    at
org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.AppClientDeployerHelper.prepareJARs(AppClientDeployerHelper.java:489)
    at
org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.NestedAppClientDeployerHelper.prepareJARs(NestedAppClientDeployerHelper.java:153)
    at
org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.AppClientDeployer.generateArtifacts(AppClientDeployer.java:293)
    at
org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.JavaEEDeployer.prepare(JavaEEDeployer.java:224)
    ... 71 more ]]
```

I also found this decode from `theAppClientDeployerHelper.java` class:

ACC007 The app client {0,choice,0#file|1#directory} {1} does not
contain a manifest; the app client container cannot process it.
Embedded programs should pass URIs with scheme "jar:" for JAR files
and scheme "file:" for directories. Cause: The file might not be a
valid app client JAR or undeployed EAR. It might be another kind of
file or have become corrupted. Action: Make sure to specify a valid
app client JAR file or an EAR which contains at least one app client.

Comment: Nice one to the person who down voted this question. If you need more info, just ask.

Comment: According to [this](https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/glassfish/appclient/server/core/src/main/resources/org/glassfish/appclient/server/core/LogStrings.properties.shtml): `enterprise.deployment.appclient.noManifest=ACDEPL002: Cannot process archive {0} as an application client; it does not contain the required manfest at META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Basically you need to inspect your `EAR` and check the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.  Could you include the exact structure of your `EAR`? (I'll post this as an answer if it is a correct solution.)

Comment: The EAR has a MANIFEST.MF file. 'Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: P
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_131'

Comment: The EAR has a MANIFEST.MF file. It has a lib folder containing common jars, a META-INF with the manifest and two WARs plus a EJB JAR. This setup has worked previously for me. I've tried retrograding back to lower versions of GF, but the problem still arises. I have added significantly more code since my last compilation and as a result there are many more supporting jar libraries. I suspect the problem is related to one of those dependencies, however the error doesn't seem to help me narrow my search. If I can get GF to display the exact error message as intended, should be easy to solve.

Comment: Hm.. Could you include an actual snapshot (/pom) of the dependencies you have? (If there is a for example a `war` packaged one it could cause some problems like this.)

Comment: Do you know how to make GF display the correct error response? Is this a bug?

Comment: You still did not included your pom. I do not think it is a bug, you just have some problems in your own `ear`.

Comment: So is the RuntimeException... Can't find resource bundle typical behaviour of GF? I haven't seen it log an error like this before. My effective POM is huge as it inherits from a number of parent poms. Too impractical to show. How would you diagnose the error from the POM?

Comment: Inspect your `ear` and `war` files and check for the `META-INF` and `WEB-INF` folders with the necessary files (application.xml, web.xml etc).

Comment: I've checked my own EAR, WARs and EJB jars. They all have the required files. I inspected for these before posting the original question.

Comment: Are there any other errors?  Based on the error posted, this would be thrown when it tries to get the error message to tell you a manifest file is missing.  Have you removed all jar files from the classpath that are no longer there?   If you look at the LogString.properties [source](https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/glassfish/appclient/server/core/src/main/resources/org/glassfish/appclient/server/core/LogStrings.properties.shtml) you can see it attempts to print the offending file at {0}.  If you can find that property file and add the missing property it may supply the answer for you

Comment: I've tried adding the property file already to the domain and root GF so it's in the classpath when uploading. But it still doesn't generate the error correctly. I'm confused as to why the property file is not used or even bundled in GF in the first place. Hence my assumption it is a bug. Perhaps I'm not configuring the properties file correctly. Also, the error seems to relate exclusively to an Appclient, which I don't have in my EAR.

Answer (score 0):

Altering the EAR plugin in Maven which auto generated the *application.xml* used by Glassfish for application deployment seemed to fix this problem. The application would actually deploy without errors in directory format using Eclipse, however remote deployment was the problem. Fixed by the following code.

```
<artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <includeLibInApplicationXml>false</includeLibInApplicationXml>
```